# Why this is not Selection sort algorithm

Tags: python, list, algorithm, selection-sort

I am trying to do selection sort algorithm but i am not able to figure out what am i missing .
give below are two codes 
Code 1 , I tried with accesing values with index and it works

Code 1 :

```
arr = [20,11,64,28,80,64,61,58,23,50,55,21,34,76,39,29,15,66,13,91,74,51]
for i in range(len(arr)):
    min_ele = i
    for j in range(i,len(arr)):
        if arr[min_ele] > arr[j]:
            min_ele = j


    arr[i],arr[min_ele] = arr[min_ele],arr[i]

print(arr)
```

But  Code 2 , i think what i was trying is mostly the same . i am comparing values and then taking their indexes and swaping with each other but somehow array is not changing at all and i can't figure it out what am i missing

Code 2:

```
arr = [20,11,64,28,80,64,61,58,23,50,55,21,34,76,39,29,15,66,13,91,74,51]
for x in arr:
    min_ele = x
    for xx in arr[arr.index(x):len(arr)]:
        if min_ele > xx:
            min_ele = xx

    arr[arr.index(x)],arr[arr.index(min_ele)] = arr[arr.index(min_ele)],arr[arr.index(x)]

print(arr)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
index_1 = arr.index(x)
index_2 = arr.index(min_ele)

arr[index_1],arr[index_2] = arr[index_2],arr[index_1]
```

but somehow this works